# What is the maximum acceleration a human can generate? With which body part?

Tags: strength, speed

As I was reading the description on the back of a gaming mouse carton, "50g of acceleration", I was thinking: "A human hand cannot possibly get close to this kind of acceleration!" The ensuing google-search only came up with results as to how much acceleration the human body can withstand, not how much it can produce, so that is why I decided to ask here:

How much acceleration can an average human being generate? (Even if it is just a short burst)

What body part generates the most? How much is it?

How much can the elbow/wrist (whatever is involved in moving a computer mouse) generate?

Comment: I'd vote for snapping your fingers or closing your eyes. Both produce a fast movement really fast. No idea how large the acceleration might be though.

Comment: I guess one could take measurements from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isuMXCYhto4

Comment: I'd second finger snapping, although blinking makes the eyelid accelerate greatly without a "force acumulator", such as the holder finger used in finger snapping.

Comment: This may be more of a physics question.  Do note that the effects of changing direction very quickly can generate more "G" forces at the peak of the direction change.  Moving a light weight object like a mouse back and forth quickly would be one reason that the mouse would have to be engineered for excessive G forces.

Comment: Baseball - 40 G's - http://www.science20.com/science_20/science_baseball_what_fastest_pitcher_can_throw-51797 - Now, if you consider implements, golf drives can exceed 100 g's at impact, hockey is similar, lacrosse sticks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the fastest movements and possibly the biggest acceleration are due to [eye saccades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade#Timing_and_kinematics), that is rapid movements of the eye as it scans the environment. Those are involuntary and have to do with perception.

Wikipedia quotes the speed at 900 degrees/second (2.5 revolutions, for comparison with ADAM). As for acceleration, "[Unsupervised clustering method to detect microsaccades](http://www.journalofvision.org/content/14/2/18.full)" (graph cut-out below) puts peak angular acceleration at cca 7000 degrees/second^2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My arm is ~84 cm long.  Earlier this evening, I timed myself doing arm swings at 20 circles/(10 seconds). That's 2 revs/second.  With a 84 cm radius, my fingertips were therefore moving 
    2*[2*pi*(0.84m)]/sec ~ 10 m/s.

Centripetal acceleration = v^2/radius.
    (7.54m/s)^2/(0.6m) ~ 120 m/s^2 ==> 12 G.

My fingertips were being accelerated back to my shoulder at almost 12 G!

Although that seems impossibly high, my fingertips felt like they were going to burst while I was doing it, and 3 hours later, as I type, that hand still feels puffy and slightly bruised - after only 20 seconds of swinging.  If my head had felt that kind of pressure I would have passed out, guaranteed.

Comment: Wow. Lots of free time on your hands. No pun intended.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the other post, so I am leaving a comment here:
`7000 deg/sec^2 = = 122 rad/sec^2` - wow!  That's really high.  The eyeball is tiny, though, so the G-forces are not all that big:
angular acceleration alpha `= 7000 deg/s^2 = = 122 rad/sec^2`
linear acceleration (tangential to radius)
`a = alpha * r`
Assume the eyeball has a radius of 1 cm = 0.01 m
`a_linear = 122 rad/sec^2 * .01 m = 1.22 m/s^2   ~= 1/8 of G.`

Comment: How about centripetal accelaration?  This is highest when the angular speed (omega) is at it's max:
`omega = 2.5 revolutions /s = 2*pi*2.5 rad/sec = 15.7 rad/sec`   [note _radians_ are actually dimensionless, so the units here are really just _per_ _second_]
`a_centrip = omega^2 *r  = 246.7/s^2  *  0.01 m = 2.5 m/sec^2 ~= 1/4 G`

So the highest _angular_ acceleration is the eye movement.  The highest _linear_ acceleration is probably swinging your arm in a circle.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I got here through the "gaming mouse can endure 50g acceleration. I don't think (and that's an opinion) that humans can produce anything like that through the end of their limbs. Turns out there's a Wikipedia site on on G-Forces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Human_tolerance. Not particularly useful except for two things. One, the Mantis shrimp can produce 10,400 g force with a claw snap. Yea for our team, I would have picked the mantis shrimp for maximum biological acceleration. (Flea acceleration for an entire animal might be a category.) The second point in the article is that a human involved in an Indianapolis Speedway crash survived momentary G forces of 214 Gs. This was deceleration and the article didn't elaborate on how the force was calculated. G forces are determined by the rate at which an object accelerates (or decellerates0 over a given interval of time. A car driver's rate of deceleration might be significantly slower than a car's rate of deceleration because the care is designed to crumple and slow down the driver's rate of deceleration. The article also mentions that a one meter drop of a rigid object onto a hard surface might generate momentary G forces of 1000 Gs. Not exactly relevant to gaming mice but . . .

Comment: "not exactly relevant" is exactly what this answer is